# controlling EV3 motor using Matlab

Tags: matlab, lego-mindstorms-ev3

im trying to control my ev3 motor speed, but when I apply this code noting happen what should I do?
thanks

```
myev3 = legoev3;

mymotor = motor(myev3,'A');

omega_1=[0  17.79123846 18.61264124 19.24807265 19.69118368 19.93754691 19.98470077 19.8321741  19.48149091 18.93615509 18.20161548 17.28521134 16.19609908 14.94516075 13.54489532 12.00929377 10.35369932 8.59465414  6.749734013 4.837372774 2.876678106 0.88724062  -1.11106188 -3.098263017    -5.054507334    -6.960248685    -8.796445531    -10.5447512 -12.1876972 -13.70886776    -15.09306385    -16.32645503    -17.39671767    -18.29315806    -19.00681925    -19.5305706 -19.85917893    -19.98936092    -19.91981582    -19.6512385 -19.18631251    -18.52968322    -17.68791146    -16.66940794    -15.48434921    -14.14457597    -12.66347481    -11.05584439    -9.337747634    -7.526351187    -5.639753927    -3.696806111    -1.716921029    0.280118959 2.274360092 4.245876571 6.174969654 8.042364482 9.829402662 11.5182287  13.0919684  14.53489749 15.83259868
];

%%
q=63;

 while q<=62    
     
    mymotor.Speed = omega_1(0:q,:);
    start(mymotor);
    pause(90);
    stop(mymotor);
    q+1;
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs while `q<=62`, but you set the value `q=63` before that.

So the program never entered the loop to begin with.

Comment: ok, I made it q=1, since Matlab start counting from 1, and the following error appears:


                      
               Error in motor/set.Speed (line 54)
            obj.Legoev3Handle.setOutputPower(obj.OutputPort, speed);


Error in ev3_circle (line 17)
    mymotor.Speed = omega_1(0:q,:);

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. `omega_1(0:q,:)` is not a valid matlab code. I'm sorry, but you need to try to fix the problem, not just ask me to debug your code.